# View Full Path of Current Document in Apps Like Preview & TextEdit

Tags: preview

I'd like to be able to view the full path of a file, rather than just its file name, in document-based apps like Preview & TextEdit. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a copy/pasteable format, but if you right-click the file name in TextEdit or Preview, it will show the path as a graphical hierarchy.

[image]

Copy/pasteable would be Get Info on the file from the Finder, I guess. Depending on the target application you can also just drag the icon from the application, e.g. into Terminal.

Comment: Right-clicking there is useful, I'd forgotten about that. The info panel doesn't display path information for me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Get Info from the Finder. I perhaps should have been clearer, will tweak the answer